# Concatenate/join rows in txt file w/ Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, concatenation

Looking to clean up a .txt file from NMEA GPS. My current code is below.

```
deletes = ['$GPGGA', '$GPGSA', '$GPGSV', '$PSRF156', ]
searchquery = '$GPRMC'

with open('Drive_home.txt_rf') as f1:
    with open('Drive_home_1.txt', 'w+') as f2:
        lines = f1.readlines()
        for i, line in enumerate(lines):
            if line.startswith(searchquery):
                if not any(delete in lines[i + 1] for delete in deletes):
                    f2.write(line)
                    f2.write(lines[i + 1])
```

Which outputs one txt. and looks like...

```
$GPRMC  204249  A   3504.5449   N   8509.0603   W   0.31    352.89  300818  A*7F                                    
    96.5    39  5   14  -2  200 0   1   0   30-08-18    16:42:46:365                                
$GPRMC  204250  A   3504.5449   N   8509.0605   W   0.32    352.89  300818  A*72                                    
    96.5    39  7   22  -3  168 0   0   0   30-08-18    16:42:47:364                                
$GPRMC  204251  A   3504.5448   N   8509.0606   W   0.77    352.89  300818  A*70                                    
    96.5    32  9   24  -2  184 0   1   0   30-08-18    16:42:48:362                                
$GPRMC  204252  A   3504.5448   N   8509.0608   W   0.37    352.89  300818  A*79                                    
    96.5    43  9   15  -4  236 0   1   0   30-08-18    16:42:49:454                                
$GPRMC  204253  A   3504.545    N   8509.0609   W   0.14    352.89  300818  A*71                                    
    96.5    37  23  17  -4  184 0   1   0   30-08-18    16:42:50:967                                
$GPRMC  204254  A   3504.545    N   8509.061    W   1.52    50.91   300818  A*45                                    
    96.5    38  10  21  -3  184 0   1   0   30-08-18    16:42:51:451
```

Is there away to join the line after "$GPRMC with next line to look like below?

```
$GPRMC  204244  A   3504.5446   N   8509.0599   W   0   352.89  300818  A*7F 96.5   40  6   11  1   236 0   1   0   30-08-18    16:42:41:451                                                                        
$GPRMC  204245  A   3504.5447   N   8509.0598   W   0.27    352.89  300818  A*7B 96.5   44  6   9   -9  236 0   1   1   30-08-18    16:42:42:434                                
$GPRMC  204246  A   3504.5447   N   8509.0598   W   0   352.89  300818  A*7D 96.5   44  7   14  1   217 0   1   0   30-08-18    16:42:43:401                                
$GPRMC  204247  A   3504.5448   N   8509.0599   W   0.25    352.89  300818  A*75 96.5   35  14  21  2   151 0   1   0   30-08-18    16:42:44:400
```

I'm not quiet sure how .join() works or if there is a way to concatenate every other line or with previous line if line.startwith. Will this be an issue joining since it has integers and floats in it?

Thanks

Edit: Sorry, should have included a sample of the output file from the GPS. See below.

```
Freq   RSSI  USN  WAM  IF   BW   AGC  ST   RDS     Date        Time
 92.3   38    4    8   -1  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:01:224
 92.3   36    4    7   -4  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:01:427
 92.3   32    4    9   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:01:614
 92.3   36    4    6   -1  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:01:817
$GPGGA,140904.698,3504.4905,N,08508.9919,W,1,04,2.3,311.8,M,-31.2,M,,0000*65
$GPGSA,A,3,29,15,05,21,,,,,,,,,6.1,2.3,5.6*3E
 92.3   35    4    8   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:02:019
$GPRMC,140904.698,A,3504.4905,N,08508.9919,W,0.46,134.55,041218,,,A*7E
 92.3   35    5    6   -3  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:02:253
 92.3   35    4    7   -1  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:02:503
 92.3   36    4    6   -4  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:02:706
 92.3   35    4    8   -5  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:02:893
$GPGGA,140905.698,3504.4907,N,08508.9917,W,1,04,2.3,312.0,M,-31.2,M,,0000*63
$GPGSA,A,3,29,15,05,21,,,,,,,,,6.1,2.3,5.6*3E
 92.3   36    4   11   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:03:096
$GPRMC,140905.698,A,3504.4907,N,08508.9917,W,0.91,134.55,041218,,,A*79
 92.3   38    4    9   -1  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:03:299
 92.3   35    4    9   -4  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:03:501
 92.3   36    3    7   -3  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:03:735
$GPGGA,140906.698,3504.4907,N,08508.9916,W,1,04,2.3,312.1,M,-31.2,M,,0000*60
 92.3   34    4    9   -3  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:03:938
$GPGSA,A,3,29,15,05,21,,,,,,,,,6.1,2.3,5.6*3E
 92.3   34    4    5   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:04:141
$GPRMC,140906.698,A,3504.4907,N,08508.9916,W,0.76,134.55,041218,,,A*72
 92.3   36    4    8   -3  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:04:344
 92.3   34    4    4   -3  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:04:547
 92.3   34    5    5   -3  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:04:734
$GPGGA,140907.698,3504.4910,N,08508.9914,W,1,04,2.3,312.2,M,-31.2,M,,0000*66
 92.3   35    4    4   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:04:937
$GPGSA,A,3,29,15,05,21,,,,,,,,,6.1,2.3,5.6*3E
 92.3   34    4    4   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:05:139
$GPGSV,3,1,12,29,67,241,27,15,56,179,23,05,39,048,23,21,29,309,12*7A
$GPGSV,3,2,12,02,25,108,21,30,03,057,19,04,62,074,,13,58,096,*7D
 92.3   30    5   14   -1  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:05:342
$GPGSV,3,3,12,26,33,051,,16,13,265,,20,13,259,,25,02,216,*70
 92.3   35    4    7   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:05:545
$GPRMC,140907.698,A,3504.4910,N,08508.9914,W,0.60,134.55,041218,,,A*70
 92.3   35    3   10   -3  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:05:857
$GPGGA,140908.698,3504.4912,N,08508.9921,W,1,04,2.3,312.4,M,-31.2,M,,0000*6B
$GPGSA,A,3,29,15,05,21,,,,,,,,,6.1,2.3,5.6*3E
 92.3   35    4    4   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:06:060
$GPRMC,140908.698,A,3504.4912,N,08508.9921,W,0.96,134.55,041218,,,A*72
 92.3   34    4    4   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:06:263
 92.3   36    4    5   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:06:465
 92.3   35    4    7   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:06:684
 92.3   34    4    4   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:06:855
$GPGGA,140909.695,3504.4913,N,08508.9922,W,1,04,2.3,312.5,M,-31.2,M,,0000*64
$GPGSA,A,3,29,15,05,21,,,,,,,,,6.1,2.3,5.6*3E
 92.3   34    5    8   -2  254    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:07:058
$GPRMC,140909.695,A,3504.4913,N,08508.9922,W,0.49,134.55,041218,,,A*7E
 92.3   34    4   10   -1  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:07:261
 92.3   35    4    8   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:07:464
 92.3   35    3   16   -1  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:07:698
$GPGGA,140910.698,3504.4917,N,08508.9923,W,1,04,2.3,312.2,M,-31.2,M,,0000*63
 92.3   35    4   10   -4  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:07:901
$GPGSA,A,3,29,15,05,21,,,,,,,,,6.1,2.3,5.6*3E
 92.3   36    4    6   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:08:103
$GPRMC,140910.698,A,3504.4917,N,08508.9923,W,2.46,122.91,041218,,,A*7C
 92.3   35    4    9   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:08:306
 92.3   35    4    6   -3  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:08:509
 92.3   35    4    5   -3  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:08:696
 92.3   34    4    4   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:08:899
$GPGGA,140911.698,3504.4922,N,08508.9925,W,1,04,2.3,312.0,M,-31.2,M,,0000*60
$GPGSA,A,3,29,15,05,21,,,,,,,,,6.1,2.3,5.7*3F
 92.3   35    5   12   -6  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:09:102
$GPRMC,140911.698,A,3504.4922,N,08508.9925,W,3.00,104.97,041218,,,A*7C
 92.3   37    5    9   -4  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:09:305
 92.3   34    4   11   -1  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:09:585
 92.3   37    4    8   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:09:788
$GPGGA,140912.698,3504.4929,N,08508.9929,W,1,05,1.7,311.6,M,-31.2,M,,0000*67
 92.3   38    3    7    0  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:09:975
$GPGSA,A,3,29,13,15,05,21,,,,,,,,3.2,1.7,2.7*3B
$GPGSV,3,1,12,29,67,241,27,13,58,096,19,15,56,179,22,05,39,048,23*72
 92.3   36    4    7   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:10:178
$GPGSV,3,2,12,21,29,309,13,02,25,108,20,30,03,057,19,04,62,074,*7C
 92.3   34    5    5   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:10:381
$GPGSV,3,3,12,26,33,051,,16,13,265,,20,13,259,,25,02,216,*70
 92.3   38    4    7   -1  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:10:615
$GPRMC,140912.698,A,3504.4929,N,08508.9929,W,2.85,89.73,041218,,,A*4A
 92.3   35    4   15   -4  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:10:818
$GPGGA,140913.698,3504.4934,N,08508.9940,W,1,05,1.7,311.2,M,-31.2,M,,0000*61
$GPGSA,A,3,29,13,15,05,21,,,,,,,,3.2,1.7,2.7*3B
 92.3   38    5    8   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:11:021
$GPRMC,140913.698,A,3504.4934,N,08508.9940,W,2.94,73.30,041218,,,A*4A
 92.3   35    4   10   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:11:223
 92.3   35    3   10   -1  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:11:411
 92.3   35    3    6   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:11:629
 92.3   36    4    6    1  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:11:816
$GPGGA,140914.698,3504.4942,N,08508.9950,W,1,05,1.7,310.6,M,-31.2,M,,0000*63
$GPGSA,A,3,29,13,15,05,21,,,,,,,,3.2,1.7,2.7*3B
 92.3   35    3    7   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:12:019
$GPRMC,140914.698,A,3504.4942,N,08508.9950,W,1.43,71.15,041218,,,A*41
 92.3   35    5    8   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:12:222
 92.3   35    4    4   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:12:425
 92.3   35    4    6   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:12:705
$GPGGA,140915.700,3504.4948,N,08508.9954,W,1,05,1.7,309.6,M,-31.2,M,,0000*64
 92.3   35    4    4   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:12:908
$GPGSA,A,3,29,13,15,05,21,,,,,,,,3.2,1.7,2.7*3B
 92.3   31    5   14   -0  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:13:095
$GPRMC,140915.700,A,3504.4948,N,08508.9954,W,1.20,70.12,041218,,,A*4D
 92.3   36    4    9   -4  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:13:298
 92.3   36    4    5   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:13:501
 92.3   37    3    6   -0  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:13:704
$GPGGA,140916.700,3504.4955,N,08508.9959,W,1,05,1.7,308.8,M,-31.2,M,,0000*69
 92.3   35    4    8   -6  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:13:985
$GPGSA,A,3,29,13,15,05,21,,,,,,,,3.2,1.7,2.7*3B
$GPRMC,140916.700,A,3504.4955,N,08508.9959,W,1.76,68.03,041218,,,A*45
 92.3   37    4   11   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:14:187
 92.3   35    3    8   -4  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:14:375
 92.3   35    4    6    2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:14:577
 92.3   35    4    4   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:14:780
$GPGGA,140917.698,3504.4958,N,08508.9964,W,1,05,1.7,308.3,M,-31.2,M,,0000*60
 92.3   36    4    9   -6  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:14:983
$GPGSA,A,3,29,13,15,05,21,,,,,,,,3.2,1.7,2.7*3B
$GPGSV,3,1,12,29,67,241,27,13,58,096,19,15,56,179,22,05,39,048,23*72
 92.3   36    4    8   -6  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:15:186
$GPGSV,3,2,12,21,29,309,12,02,25,108,21,30,03,057,19,04,62,074,*7C
 92.3   34    4    5   -3  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:15:388
$GPGSV,3,3,12,26,33,051,,16,13,265,,20,13,259,,25,02,216,*70
$GPRMC,140917.698,A,3504.4958,N,08508.9964,W,0.76,68.03,041218,,,A*46
 92.3   34    4    5   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:15:639
 92.3   35    4    9   -5  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:15:842
$GPGGA,140918.698,3504.4955,N,08508.9968,W,1,05,1.7,307.5,M,-31.2,M,,0000*67
$GPGSA,A,3,29,13,15,05,21,,,,,,,,3.2,1.7,2.7*3B
 92.3   34    5    5   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:16:044
$GPRMC,140918.698,A,3504.4955,N,08508.9968,W,1.74,71.84,041218,,,A*4C
 92.3   35    5    6   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:16:226
 92.3   35    5    4   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:16:452
 92.3   34    5   10   -3  254    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:16:652
 92.3   36    4    7   -3  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:16:844
$GPGGA,140919.700,3504.4956,N,08508.9971,W,1,05,1.7,306.9,M,-31.2,M,,0000*60
$GPGSA,A,3,29,13,15,05,21,,,,,,,,3.2,1.7,2.7*3B
 92.3   33    4   12   -3  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:17:044
$GPRMC,140919.700,A,3504.4956,N,08508.9971,W,1.19,72.35,041218,,,A*44
 92.3   35    4    4   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:17:427
 92.3   35    5    5   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:17:630
 92.3   35    4    4   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:17:817
$GPGGA,140920.700,3504.4955,N,08508.9974,W,1,05,1.7,306.6,M,-31.2,M,,0000*63
$GPGSA,A,3,29,13,15,05,21,,,,,,,,3.2,1.7,2.7*3B
 92.3   35    4    4   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:18:020
$GPRMC,140920.700,A,3504.4955,N,08508.9974,W,1.26,73.61,041218,,,A*44
 92.3   37    4    8   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:18:222
 92.3   36    4    7   -5  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:18:425
 92.3   35    4   11   -1  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:18:612
 92.3   36    5    9   -3  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:18:815
$GPGGA,140921.698,3504.4958,N,08508.9971,W,1,05,1.7,305.8,M,-31.2,M,,0000*67
$GPGSA,A,3,29,13,15,05,21,,,,,,,,3.2,1.7,2.7*3B
 92.3   34    5    5   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:19:018
$GPRMC,140921.698,A,3504.4958,N,08508.9971,W,1.52,77.10,041218,,,A*4C
 92.3   35    4    6   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:19:221
 92.3   36    4    6   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:19:424
 92.3   35    4    5   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:19:626
 92.3   34    5   13   -3  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:19:845
$GPGGA,140922.698,3504.4954,N,08508.9977,W,1,05,1.7,305.0,M,-31.2,M,,0000*66
$GPGSA,A,3,29,13,15,05,21,,,,,,,,3.2,1.7,2.7*3B
 92.3   35    5    5   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:20:016
$GPGSV,3,1,12,29,67,241,27,13,58,096,19,15,56,179,22,05,39,048,23*72
 92.3   37    5    8   -5  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:20:297
$GPGSV,3,2,12,21,29,309,11,02,25,108,21,30,03,057,20,04,62,074,*75
$GPGSV,3,3,12,26,33,051,,16,13,265,,20,13,259,,25,02,216,*70
 92.3   36    3    4   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:20:484
$GPRMC,140922.698,A,3504.4954,N,08508.9977,W,1.42,79.28,041218,,,A*41
 92.3   36    3    7   -4  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:20:703
$GPGGA,140923.698,3504.4955,N,08508.9982,W,1,05,1.7,304.2,M,-31.2,M,,0000*6F
 92.3   37    4    8   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:20:890
$GPGSA,A,3,29,13,15,05,21,,,,,,,,3.2,1.7,2.8*34
 92.3   37    3    4   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:21:108
$GPRMC,140923.698,A,3504.4955,N,08508.9982,W,1.62,82.46,041218,,,A*45
 92.3   38    2    7   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:21:296
 92.3   38    3    7   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:21:498
 92.3   37    4    8   -3  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:21:701
$GPGGA,140924.698,3504.4956,N,08508.9989,W,1,05,1.7,303.7,M,-31.2,M,,0000*62
 92.3   38    3    5   -4  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:21:982
$GPGSA,A,3,29,13,15,05,21,,,,,,,,3.2,1.7,2.8*34
$GPRMC,140924.698,A,3504.4956,N,08508.9989,W,0.50,82.46,041218,,,A*4A
 92.3   37    4    8   -5  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:22:185
 92.3   37    3    4   -4  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:22:388
 92.3   37    3    8   -5  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:22:590
 92.3   38    3    5    0  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:22:778
$GPGGA,140925.698,3504.4958,N,08508.9999,W,1,05,1.7,303.2,M,-31.2,M,,0000*69
 92.3   38    2    5   -6  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:22:980
$GPGSA,A,3,29,13,15,05,21,,,,,,,,3.2,1.7,2.8*34
$GPRMC,140925.698,A,3504.4958,N,08508.9999,W,1.56,77.91,041218,,,A*43
 92.3   39    3    5   -3  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:23:183
 92.3   40    3    4    0  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:23:370
 92.3   39    2    3   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:23:589
 92.3   40    2    4   -5  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:23:792
$GPGGA,140926.698,3504.4963,N,08509.0003,W,1,05,1.7,302.4,M,-31.2,M,,0000*67
$GPGSA,A,3,29,13,15,05,21,,,,,,,,3.2,1.7,2.8*34
 92.3   39    3    3   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:24:057
$GPRMC,140926.698,A,3504.4963,N,08509.0003,W,1.36,74.67,041218,,,A*46
 92.3   38    3    8   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:24:260
 92.3   38    3    4   -1  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:24:462
 92.3   38    3    3   -3  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:24:665
 92.3   39    3    5   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:24:868
$GPGGA,140927.698,3504.4967,N,08509.0008,W,1,05,1.7,302.2,M,-31.2,M,,0000*6F
$GPGSA,A,3,29,13,15,05,21,,,,,,,,3.2,1.7,2.8*34
 92.3   38    3    9   -5  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:25:149
$GPGSV,3,1,12,29,67,241,26,13,58,096,19,15,56,179,22,05,39,048,24*74
$GPGSV,3,2,12,21,29,309,12,02,25,108,21,30,03,057,20,04,62,074,*76
 92.3   38    3    3   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:25:336
$GPGSV,3,3,12,26,33,051,,16,13,265,,20,13,259,,25,02,216,*70
 92.3   38    3    3   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:25:539
$GPRMC,140927.698,A,3504.4967,N,08509.0008,W,0.80,74.67,041218,,,A*44
 92.3   38    4    3   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:25:742
$GPGGA,140928.698,3504.4969,N,08509.0015,W,1,05,1.7,302.0,M,-31.2,M,,0000*60
 92.3   38    3    3   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:25:944
$GPGSA,A,3,29,13,15,05,21,,,,,,,,3.2,1.7,2.8*34
 92.3   41    3    4    1  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:26:147
$GPRMC,140928.698,A,3504.4969,N,08509.0015,W,0.42,74.67,041218,,,A*47
 92.3   38    3    5   -1  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:26:350
 92.3   38    3    4   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:26:631
 92.3   37    3    4   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:26:818
$GPGGA,140929.698,3504.4968,N,08509.0021,W,1,05,1.7,301.9,M,-31.2,M,,0000*6D
$GPGSA,A,3,29,13,15,05,21,,,,,,,,3.2,1.7,2.8*34
 92.3   36    4    3   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:27:021
$GPRMC,140929.698,A,3504.4968,N,08509.0021,W,0.47,74.67,041218,,,A*45
 92.3   37    4    3   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:27:224
 92.3   37    3    3   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:27:426
 92.3   37    4    4   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:27:629
 92.3   40    5    6   -5  311    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:27:816
$GPGGA,140930.698,3504.4969,N,08509.0019,W,1,05,1.7,301.8,M,-31.2,M,,0000*6E
$GPGSA,A,3,29,13,15,05,21,,,,,,,,3.2,1.7,2.8*34
 92.3   37    3    6   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:28:019
$GPRMC,140930.698,A,3504.4969,N,08509.0019,W,1.30,77.13,041218,,,A*46
 92.3   40    3    6   -1  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:28:222
 92.3   38    4    7   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:28:425
 92.3   38    3    4   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:28:628
 92.3   38    4    6   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:28:830
$GPGGA,140931.698,3504.4968,N,08509.0022,W,1,05,1.7,301.7,M,-31.2,M,,0000*69
$GPGSA,A,3,29,13,15,05,21,,,,,,,,3.2,1.7,2.8*34
 92.3   37    3    5   -1  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:29:018
$GPRMC,140931.698,A,3504.4968,N,08509.0022,W,1.03,77.13,041218,,,A*4E
 92.3   38    3    5   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:29:220
 92.3   38    3    7   -1  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:29:501
 92.3   37    3    5   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:29:704
$GPGGA,140932.698,3504.4968,N,08509.0025,W,1,05,1.7,301.6,M,-31.2,M,,0000*6C
 92.3   38    3    6   -2  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:29:907
$GPGSA,A,3,29,13,15,05,21,,,,,,,,3.2,1.7,2.8*34
 92.3   38    5    7   -8  236    0    1    1    12/4/2018  09:09:30:110
```

Comment: Can you show an example of the input file?

Comment: Normally, you are asked to copy the text of the file in the question. Here, you want to process that (damned) text, and when I copy/paste from your question I find: 1/ the printing characters of the first line end at column 80, which let think to a folding problem and 2/ there are 36 space after that last printing character. Without being sure whether it the the actual file design or a copy/paste problem, I cannot propose a way to join every second line. You should try to provide a hexa dump of the 4 initial lines to make sure.

Comment: Sorry guys, added a sample of the input file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
deletes = ['$GPGGA', '$GPGSA', '$GPGSV', '$PSRF156', ]
searchquery = '$GPRMC'

with open('Drive_home.txt_rf') as f1, open('Drive_home_1.txt', 'w+') as f2:
    lines = f1.readlines()
    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.startswith(searchquery) and not any(delete in lines[i + 1] for delete in deletes):
            f2.write(f'{line.rstrip()} {lines[i+1]}')
```

think it will work, no?

Comment: This gives me the same output that I'm already getting. Though it did clean the code up a little!

Comment: guess you have '\n' somewhere inside, can "rstrip()"